# Why can't I make a POST request to my local server?

Tags: node.js, post, request, cors, postman

First i have to precise that i'm a real beginner so please forgive me if i use wrong terms, ill try to be as clear as i can.

Context : I'm trying to develop a chat-box for my website thanks to openai API with a custom assistant i made.

The problem i'm facing is the following :

When i send a post request to my server from my website.js script i get a 405 Method not allowed while when i send the same request from POSTMAN everything works fine.
Here is a screen capture of the error :
[Inspector firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wav4c.png)
I saw that 'POST' is missing in Allow section of the response header, is this normal ?
This is my script.js code for the fetch request :

```
 fetch('/nvmsg', {                      
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: userInput }),
```

and my back-end code (node.js) for the endpoint :

```
app.post('/nvmsg', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Corps de la requête: ', req.body);
    const userMessage = req.body.message;
    console.log('Message reçu : ', userMessage);
```

I did some researches and i found that it may come from the CORS even if my server is running on the same port that my website (3000), so i add this lines on the very top of my back-end code :

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*' , 
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'], 
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], 
    credentials: false, 
}));
```

Also i'm using express, openai, cors and dotenv,  don't know if it matters.

I check the end-point many times, try in private session to ensure that it's not a cache or cookie issue with the versions of the front-end & back-end applications.

Thanks in advance for any help

Good day

Comment: Drop the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your request. It doesn't belong there. Also, I think you need to send your request to an absolute URI, e.g. `https://your-server-host/nvmsg`; as written, your client code sends a request to a `/nvmsg` path on the _client_'s (not the _server_'s) Web origin, which seems incorrect.